# HighCharts zoom with mouse wheel in react

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

## Intro

Hi I'm new to react and new to Highcharts but have worked with js before. I have a zoom function, I'd like to convert this to react code. I'm having hard time figuring out how to use `Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push` in the context of react.

## What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to create a zoom function that is smooth with the mouse wheel on a stock chart. The popular platform trading view has a very smooth zoom and I'm trying to do something similar to that.

## The code:

I have the code working decently in a js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/drewscatterday/84shran6/ but I'm having hard time converting this to react.

I have tried doing this in my react code but had no luck:

```
 const handleScroll= (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        var chart = Highcharts.chart;
        var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        extremes = xAxis.getExtremes(),
        newMin = extremes.min,
        output = [];

        if (e.deltaY < 0) {
            xAxis.setExtremes(extremes.min - (extremes.min * 0.001), extremes.max, true);
        }
        else {
            xAxis.setExtremes(extremes.min + (extremes.min * 0.001), extremes.max, true);
        }
    }

<div className="Chartdisplay__chart" id="chart" onScroll={handleScroll}>
                <StockChart options={stockOptions} highcharts={Highcharts} />
</div>
```

I have also just tried adding the function straight up like this but also had no luck:

```
let ar = [];
  (function(H) {
    Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function(chart) {
      H.addEvent(chart.container, 'mousewheel', function(e) {
        var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        extremes = xAxis.getExtremes();

        if (e.deltaY < 0) {
            xAxis.setExtremes(extremes.min - (extremes.min * 0.001), extremes.max, true);
        }
        else {
            xAxis.setExtremes(extremes.min + (extremes.min * 0.001), extremes.max, true);
        }
      });
    });
  }(Highcharts));
```

## Thank you for anyone who takes the time to read this and help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend Higstock in React.js put the code that you want to wrap before the configuration object (options).

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

  (function(H) {
    Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function(chart) {
      H.addEvent(chart.container, 'wheel', function(e) {
        var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        extremes = xAxis.getExtremes(),
        newMin = extremes.min;
        
        console.log(extremes); 
        console.log(newMin);
        
        if (e.deltaY < 0) {
            xAxis.setExtremes(extremes.min - (extremes.min * 0.001), extremes.max, true);
        }
        else {
            xAxis.setExtremes(extremes.min + (extremes.min * 0.001), extremes.max, true);
        }
      });
    });
  }(Highcharts)); 

const options = {
  title: {
    text: 'My chart'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        enableMouseTracking: true
    }
}
```

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hmvz2z?file=index.js

Comment: Thank you so much Sebastian this helped me immensely. I figured out the issue was two things. I had a typo in my react code. The event that I was checking for was ```mousewheel``` in my react code and not ```wheel```. I also realized I was defining this callback function within another function which was causing it not to do anything. 

I'm embarking on a fun project to try and recreate some of the beautiful charts that TradingView has so I imagine I'll be posting on the highcharts stackoverflow again soon with another silly issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Highcharts support team is waiting for any questions from you about the library.